# How to execute in first a function and in second canActivate()

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, canactivate

I have this AuthGuard. In this code I want to create a condition. If my resetpasss is not null I want to navigate in here ResetPassIdComponent else I want to navigate in LoginFirstComponent.

For this I create AuthGuard.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    myappurl: any;
    resetpasss: any;
    constructor(private router: Router, private auth: LoginService) {
    }
    geturl() {
        handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
            console.log('Got the following appURL1', appURL);
            this.myappurl = appURL
            let url_1 = this.myappurl.toString();
            let url_id = url_1.split("/").reverse()[0];
            this.resetpasss = url_id
            let LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
            LS.setItem(this.resetpasss)
            // this.router.navigateByUrl('/resetPasswordRequest/' + this.resetpasss);
            console.log('this.resetpass1', this.resetpasss)
        });
        return true;
    }
    canActivate(): boolean {
        this.geturl();
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log('this.resetpasss2', this.resetpasss)
        this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']);
        return false;
    }
 }
```

I click a link from email, this link show me in `geturl(){..}`. From this function `geturl(){..}` I get an id and save in localstorage. Now in canActivate() I want to create a condition that navigate me in a component that I want.

Can you ask me any idea how to create a condition?

My routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'outsidelogin',
    component: outsideloginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ]
  },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent }
];
```

Comment: is `handleOpenURL` asynchronous ?

Comment: I use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-urlhandler

Comment: do you got any errors in console?

Comment: this.resetpasss2 is undefined

Comment: as @ArtyomAmiryan asked is your handleOpenURL() is asynchronous?

Comment: I think that no. handleOpenURL() Execute on app launch

Comment: is handleOpenURL() running or not? if then I find out that it' deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335313/8348558

Comment: My `handleOpenURL()` execute correct when I click URL. Only problem is, how to call in canActivate this.resetpasss and navigate in here`this.router.navigateByUrl('/resetPasswordRequest/' + this.resetpasss);`

Comment: Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the condition in **CanActivate()** itself. Can you tried like the below?

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    this.geturl();
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    } else if(this.resetpasss){
       this.router.navigate([this.myappurl]);
    }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to navigate direct in this component ResetPassIdComponent when I click a link ?

Comment: `this.resetpasss` is undefined and navigate direct in  `this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']);`

Comment: Can you see my demo please github.com/binaau/auth_guard After installed, please click this link stackoverflow.com/questions/53921510 and open with app. In this moment you can see that application in first navigate in login component and in second in reset pass. I want to navigate directly in reset pass only when I click link. Thank you!